# Always anonymous user when using render_to_response in django code

Tags: python, django

Im using Django 1.3.1.In my django code, i have the following template for the main page, its called main_page.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
{% if user.username %}
   <p>Welcome {{ user.username }}!</p>
{% else %}
   <p>Welcome anonymous user!
   You need to <a href="/login/">login</a>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following view for this template:

```
def main_page(request):
  template = get_template('main_page.html')
  variables = Context({'user': request.user})
  output = template.render(variables)
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

This works as expected,i.e. it checks if the user has already logged in or not and greets accordingly. But if i replace the above view with the code below, then i always get the message for anonymous user on the main page, irrespective of whether i have logged in or not.

```
def main_page(request):
  return render_to_response(
      'main_page.html',
       {'user': request.user}
  )
```

What could be going wrong here ?. Please help.

Thank You

Comment: I don't see any causes for this behaviour. I've created a test project with your view functions, and can't reproduce your problem. What django version are you using? Check your code - maybe you forgot to tell us something important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the template you should use `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` instead of your `{% if user.username %}`. That should solve your problem.

On the other hand, I don't know, why you're trying to explicitly add the `user` variable in the view. Why not using something like:

```
def main_page(request):
  return render_to_response(
      'main_page.html',
       context_instance=RequestContext(request)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But im still facing the problem even with the changes you suggested.Dont know why render_to_response not working. I have done from django.template import Context,RequestContext and from django.shortcuts import render_to_response too. Anything else i can try ?

Comment: Even better, use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead, which renders with a  RequestContext automatically.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried using Django Debug Toolbar app? It would show exactly what your template variabes are when accessing main page. Link: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/

Comment: Im really surprised its working now with render_to_reponse !.I have setup Django Debug Toolbar and it is showing the user object in the context passed to the  template.

Comment: Great, so the problem is solved? :) As noted by others, you can replace `render_to_response` with `render` as of Django 1.3. In your case: `return render(request, 'main_page.html')`

Comment: Yes its working now Jakub :). What i notice is that my earlier code for the main_page view, the one you posted which uses RequestContext and the render method,all of them work if in the template i use user directly i.e. user.username or user.is_authenticated. I face the problem if i use request.user.username or request.user.is_authenticated in the template,even if the request object is being passed to the template. Any reason behind this ?

Comment: Looks like i need to have the following in settings.py for the request object to work in the template: `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

  'django.core.context_processors.request',
 
)`. This wasnt there in my settings.py earlier so the request object was not working :)

Comment: I wouldn't think that should [matter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors). The request object works with the default settings, and it's not in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` by default.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why that doesn't work. is the user variable definitely correct in the view? (try printing it to the console or dropping into a debugger). is it posible that it works with a request context because the auth context processor is already adding `user` to your context?

as of django 1.3, there is a new shortcut [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/)

```
render(request, template, dictionary)
```

if you are just looking to save on typing

Comment: I did print request.user in my main_page view. It correctly shows the current user in the console. But for some strange reason this is not being communicated correctly to the template ! :(

Comment: is using e.g. render not an option?